# AspxGridview with all checkbox column

Tags: aspxgridview

i have a devexpress grid with

dxwgv:GridViewDataCheckColumn Caption="ONE" FieldName="ONE">

i have all columns with checkbox + there is checkbox on rowselect
e.g. 
checbox | column(checkbox) | column(checkbox) |  column(checkbox) | column(checkbox)

the problem is to get the row values when any of the column checkbox is checked/unchecked.
i tried using Eval and adding to ClientInstanceName of the checkbox but sending clientInstanceName to from javascrit as params is problem (i used "chkbox_id.ClientInstanceName" but did not worked)

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the client instance name on the grid:

```
ClientInstanceName="YourGrid"
```

then add a control some where on the page to allow the user to "Select All" like so:

```
<input id="chkSelectAll" type="checkbox" onclick="YourGrid.SelectAllRowsOnPage(this.checked);" />
```

Finally in the code behind you can do something like this:

```
// aColumnName is the name of the column from which you want the value.
private List<object> GetSelectedRowValues(string aColumnName) 
    {
        List<object> values = new List<object>();
        string[] valueToGet = { aColumnName };

        for (int i = 0; i < YourGrid.VisibleRowCount; i++)
        {
            if (YourGrid.Selection.IsRowSelected(i))
            {
                //get the passed in value for the selected rows.
                values.Add(YourGrid.GetRowValues(i, valueToGet));
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
```